# VBA GetObject utilizando variável no registro do Windows 10 Projeto Swing

Tags: java, swing, vba, macro, windows-10

Olá.

Estou com um problema em um componente aqui da empresa. O aplicativo é construído em Swing com java 6. Utilizamos um framework chamado **JIntegra**.

Temos uma funcionalidade onde o usuário clica no botão para adicionar um texto. O Word é aberto dando a possibilidade do usuário colocar o texto desejado, após o término ele vai na aba "suplementos" e clica no botão que aciona uma macro (VBA). O problema está justamente nesse momento, quando chega no trecho abaixo:

`GetObject("jvm:com.empresa.classe")`

No windows 7 funcionava corretamente, mas agora com o windows 10 ele não funciona. Dá o erro:

> "Erro em tempo de execução ‘-2147221020 (80040e4). Erro de automação"

Inicialmente achávamos que o problema era nos componentes do JIntegra, porém já atualizei todas as bibliotecas do mesmo, inclusive as que são geradas pelo componente com base no word e excel, mas o erro permanece exatamente igual!

Já tentei de várias formas e não funciona. Acredito que o problema esteja no modo como o windows guarda as informações. No windows 7 o GetObject consegue encontrar o registro no windows e encontra a classe, seguindo corretamente o fluxo do script VBA. Já no windows 10 não. Sei que teve muita alteração no windows 10 e acredito que seja isso que esteja impactando no programa. Posso estar errado, mas acredito que o problema esteja relacionado ao windows.

Agradeço quem puder ajudar.
Paulo

Comment: Já tentou usar o modo de compatibilidade?

Comment: Boa tarde. Não tentei. Seria pelo windows, indo em propriedades, ou setando no código?

Comment: Pelo OS em propriedades.

Comment: Não existem outras diferenças entre os dois ambientes, como versão do office ou arquitetura dele (x86 ou x64)?

Comment: Leandro. Sim, o ambiente antigo era 32, o novo 64.